# How to e-mail an offline webpage?

Tags: html, css, offline, hotmail

I was wondering if there is a way to upload an offline webpage (css, html and some images) into an email. Then send a link to the index.html for the user to click on.

I work for a television production company so the content is not allowed to actually go online. This is part of a pitch so online a small file size.

Thanks!

Comment: Why would a HTML-formatted e-mail not work?

Comment: that's not how emails work. you can send the webpage as a zip or something. edit: to expand on this: If it's just one page maybe send it directly as a html email.

Comment: if it is just html you can send the files and ask them to open the index file. if you have some server side you need to follow a different way

Comment: Could you not use a HTML email? That way you don't have to worry about the content being stored anywhere and it's a lot easier than setting up some gated content.

Comment: Your best choice is to zip the files and send it via email. If you wanna send html emails, than you will have many issues, because email clients do not allow 90% of styles and scripts embedded.

Comment: I know some programs such as local by flywheel allow you to have a temporary live link for your local copy. Did you try something like that.

Comment: Yes - simply add the html file as an attachment and then the user can simply open the file with a web browser. I feel that this question should be closed because it's not really a programming question asking for help with an issue...